# Created a new OpenSSL key and I don't know where my CSR file is?

Tags: ssh, ssl, openssl

Still learning a lot about Ubuntu and server management.

I need to generate a new SSL certificate and I have followed a tutorial on how to create the CSR file.

I ran the following command:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout [serverName].key -out [serverName].csr
```

I then filled out the information needed.
I believe I have created the .CSR file but I don't know where.

I need this obviously to get the SSL certificate so where should I find it to download it to?

THANK YOU.

Answer (score 2):

Search for the file in your system with:

```
sudo find / -name "[server name].csr"
```

Comment: Created an account just to upvote this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With this command, you don't choose a directory for your key, so normally, your key is created where you are when you run the command.
I personally use this and it works well:

```
openssl req -out CSR.csr -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout privateKey.key
```

You don't see it with `ls -l`? You could try to run `find` or `locate` with the name you chose.